# phonegap how to pass parameter to executeSql function?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I have query like below;

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {

             for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                   var table = localSyncRecords[i].ActionTable.toString();
                   tx.executeSql("Select * From Client", [], function (tx, resp) { alert(table) }, function (tx, resp) {}); 

           } // for loop
 });
```

When I executed this query, it alerts same table name everytime.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this solution;

```
db.transaction( function(tx){ your_function(tx, parameter1, parameter2) }, ErrorCallBack );
```